# Why I receive this message Jira RESTApi error response

Tags: jira-rest-api

I am trying to create a Jira POST in order to create a JIRA ticket. However, I receive this mesage as a response from Postman.

```
{
    "errorMessages": [],
    "errors": {
        "project": "project is required"
    }
}
```

And my Body is like:

```
{   
    "fields": {
       "project":
       {
          "key": "TEST"
       },
       "summary": "First attemp from Postman",
       "description": "Creating of an issue using IDs for projects and issue types using the REST API",
       "issuetype":
       {
          "name": "Bug"
       }
   }
}
```

Please there is any chance to fix this?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `"project": "ABC?"` ?

Comment: I change it as you proposed :

```
{   
    "fields": {
       "project": "ABC",
       "summary": "First attemp from Postman",
       "description": "Creating of an issue using IDs for projects and issue types using the REST API",
       "issuetype":
       {
          "name": "Bug"
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: But the response is the same

Comment: Well, did you create a project called "ABC" in Jira?

Comment: Actually, I want to create an issue from the Jira API with curl. I do not know if I was not clear in my first post.

Comment: You need a project to create an issue in.

Comment: Hello, I did something like that and I received this.

{
    "errorMessages": [],
    "errors": {
        "customfield_10852": "To be fixed in release is required.",
        "customfield_10390": "Technical Area is required.",
        "customfield_10383": "Reporting Team is required.",
        "customfield_10385": "Occurred in environment is required.",
        "customfield_10352": "Reported in Project is required.",
        "customfield_10870": "Reported in release is required.",
        "customfield_10871": "Entity is required.",
}

Comment: I need to pass other parameters on the Rest Api... But how exaclty?

Comment: Now I have to add "customfield_XXXXX" into PUT/POST query.....